# Selenium - {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"} has no method 'indexOf'

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I totally understand want is happening, but can't find a way around the issue. 
Here is the code :

```
el    = driver.findElement(By.css('#mailmillieu a'));
text  = el.getAttribute("href"); 
text  = fqdn + text.substring( text.indexOf("/parse_actions") );
driver.get(text);
```

Here is the error message :

```
TypeError: Object Promise::340 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"} has no method 'indexOf'
```

How can I tell Selenium to wait until the promise is fullfilled or rejected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *explicitly resolve the promise* with `then()`:

```
text.then(function (textValue) {
    textValue  = fqdn + textValue.substring( textValue.indexOf("/parse_actions") );
    driver.get(textValue);
});
```